# Matrices - Gaussian Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

How to know which process should be done **first and second** in Gaussian elimination?
What is the algorithm for this process or any easy way?

---

Solving the Linear equation in a normal way takes less time than Gaussian elimination method because there are arrays of methods that can be done in order to do this.

---

[image: The sample methods that should be done in order to apply Gauss Elimination]

Comment: You have to turn the two first entries of the row of z to 0, the first and last entry of the row of y to 0, the last two entries of the row of x to 0...

Answer (score 0):

I know this post was made a while ago, but here is my answer for future reference.

Gaussian Elimination is a nice way of organizing the coefficients and information of a linear system. It gives you a clear start to end to evaluate any situation. If someone gave me 25 variables and 25 different equations relating those variables together and asked me to solve those using traditional high school scaling and canceling stuff off, I would be confused about where to even start.

(I organize my matrices so the final matrix has zeros on the bottom left corner of the matrix)

Getting entries that should become zero to be zero always is achievable by dividing one row by the value of the entry so that the new entry becomes one, and getting another row to do the same thing, but multiply it by $-1$ so that the entry in another row (same column) is $-1$. When you add the two rows, the $+1$ and $-1$ add to make zero. There could be faster ways though.